# Confusion about big-O notation comparison of two functions

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

On page 16 of this [algorithms book](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/all.pdf), it states:

> For example, suppose we are choosing between two algorithms for a particular computational task. One takes $f_1(n) = n^2$ steps, while the other takes $f_2(n) = 2n + 20$ steps (Figure 0.2).

He then goes on to say:

> This superiority ... (of $f_2$ over $f_1$) ... is captured by the big-O notation: $f_2 = O(f_1)$, because ...

Now my problem is that in the original quote, he said that $f_1(n) = n^2$ steps and $f_2(n) = 2n+20$ steps, so thus $f_1 = O(n^2)$ and $f_2 = O(n)$ (big-O is defined in Section 0.3). But the second quote above states $f_2 = O(f_1)$, which means $f_2 = O(n^2)$ and contradicts his definition of big-O notation. What have I missed?

Comment: The $=$ is a huge abuse of notation. I wonder if it wasn't chosen over $\in$ mostly for the convenience of typing it.

Comment: @Joe: likely, though there is a closely related usage along the lines of  $f = a + bx + cx^2 + O(x^3)$ for Taylor series. If you consider the special case $a,b,c= 0$, it would be quite tempting to simply write $f = O(x^3)$; but it feels really awkward (though it is more correct) to write $f \in a + bx + cx^2 + O(x^3)$. The fact that physicists (and other mathematicians) routinely write this sort of thing on black/white boards more or less suggests that the difficulty of writing $\in$ isn't the entire issue either. It's a place where good usage and idiom are at odds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key thing to keep in mind here is that the equals sign in $f = O(g)$ does not behave as an equals sign usually would. The reason is that $O(g)$ is not actually a function but a **set** of functions. For example, you can think of $O(n^2)$ as being a set which, among many other functions, contains the functions $n$, $5 \sqrt n$, $\log^5 n$, etc. So as the appropriate way to think of $f = O(g)$ is not as equality but instead as being an element of a set: $f \in O(g)$.

So the set $O(n)$ is a subset of $O(n^2)$ since any function that is asymptotically bounded above by a multiple of $n$ is also bounded asymptotically above by a multiple of $n^2$.

Answer (score 4):

The big-O denotes an **upper bound**. Since $O(n)\subset O(n^2) $, we have for any function $h$
$$h=O(n)\; \Rightarrow \; h= O(n^2).$$

In other words if $g_1(n)=n$ is an asymptotic upper bound for $f_2(n)$ then $g_2(n)=n^2$ is of course also an asymptotic upper bound for $f_2(n)$. The statement does not contradict the definition of the big-O definition.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply; what confuses me is what is the purpose in saying that $h = O(n) \Rightarrow h = O(n^2)$. Because we could say that $h = O(n^{2382})$ which is also an upper bound. What's the point in talking about anything but the least upper bound?

Comment: Well, usually you want to have **good upper bounds**. However, technically there is nothing wrong with it, when you say $h=O(n^{2382})$. It's just not a very strong statement. Notice that there is also the notion of $\Theta()$ which denotes a tight bound. The problem is, that it is often challenging to derive a $\Theta()$ bound, and that is why you stick to the big-O notation.

Comment: Sometimes we simply don't know the least upper bound.  We can do matrix multiplication in $O(n^3)$, and even in $O(n^{2.38})$.  It is a huge open question whether we can do it in $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Right, so in the case described in my original question, all we're really saying is that $f_2$ has equal or less time complexity than $f_1$, but on the other hand $f_1$'s complexity is not contained in $O(f_2)$ because $f_2 = O(n)$? I think the notation is odd, maybe it should be $f_2 \in O(f_1)$.

Comment: Since you still have problems with the big-O, notation I recommend that you have a look at our FAQ question http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57.

Comment: @DesmondWolf:  Indeed, the equality sign is slightly misleading as it is not symmetric.  Membership is more correct, but when we speak about it, we really say "$f_2$ *is* $O(n)$", and then the equality sign seems more natural.